# Android Studio NDK issue

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I have a problem. I have an app which works fine on Android 5 & 6. The app has c++ shared lib refference. The problem is: When I compile and assembling to .apk without selecting my 4.0.3 device as target for execution then after installing it`s failing in my native code. But when I`m trying to address this issue via debug everything works just fine. Is it possible that Android Studio is adding some additional parameters to build configuration without which app wont run.
Thank  you.

Comment: It is perfectly normal that native code compiled for platform-21 will not work on device with platform-15. With NDK, there is no forward-compatibility, but there is pretty high backward compatibility. So, if you build for platform-15, your app can still run on Android 5, and you can use `targetSdkVersion 23`. You need to set `platformVersion 15` inside **`android.ndk {}`**.

Comment: *address this issue via debug* is not exactly clear. Please explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the problem is with my  lz4 implementation which several years ago I've taken from windows app. There was a lot if stuff like:

```
#define U32     uint32_t

void* source = {some void pointer}
void* destination = {some void pointer}
*(U32*)destination = *(U32*)source;
```

I've found on internet implementation of lz4 for Androin and noticed that the differens is in using memcpy not (U32) = (U32). I have rewritten my code to exclude all places like this and it started to work on my 4.0.3.